# Spring Data JPA - How to find nested objects by parental object's id?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Some object:

```
public class SomeObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "someObject")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<NestedObject> nestedObjects;

    // ...
}
```

Nested object:

```
public class NestedObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SomeObject someObject;

    // ...
}
```

I can find all nested objects by *findAll* method, but I can't find nested objects by *someObject*'s id or itself (I'm getting empty collection).

```
public interface NestedObject Repository extends JpaRepository<NestedObject , Long> {

    Collection<NestedObject> findBySomeObject_Id(Long id);

    Collection<NestedObject> findBySomeObject(SomeObject someObject);
}
```

Comment: What is the underlying SQL logging? Up the logging, find out and check there is definitely data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget initialize *SomeObject* in *NestedObject*s in *SomeObject*'s constructor:

```
    for (NestedObject nestedObject: nestedObjects)
        nestedObject.setSomeObject(this);
```